# How can I make my Keyboard and touchpad work after resuming from suspend in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, suspend

My machine runs seemingly perfect until I resume from suspend at which point I have no input capabilities.  System is completely unresponsive to any physical activity performed on the keyboard and mouse touchpad/mouse buttons. I can however hook up a USB mouse and use that (assuming the same for USB keyboard but haven't tried yet).

Any ideas how to resolve this?

**Setting:**

- Asus K61IC-A1
- Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic Koala 64 bit

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a bug. I know I had this same exact issue on a dell laptop with Karmic. Have you searched through the ubuntu bugs? Have you posted this as a bug?

> please see
>   http://bugs.archlinux.org/task/14046
>   (reloading AT interface works for me,
>   at least) and they state that this
>   issue is fixed as of
>   xserver-xorg-input-evdev 2.3.1 - you
>   could test eg. lucid package for evdev
>   http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xserver-xorg-input-evdev

These instructions helped me.

Answer (score 1):

It happens to me.  I have no answer yet, but if you click on "Log in as different user", and select back your same account (I have Invited user available), it will let you use keyboard again, although touchpad will be useless yet.